# How to get message headers in an interceptor in Spring-Integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-ws

I'm using Spring-Integration to proxy a SOAP Webservice. I get the request using some inbound gateway and after some transformations, the message passes a `ws:outbound-gateway`. I extended `ClientInterceptor` and define a custom one with the name `WSLoggingInterceptor` which logs XML requests and responses and added it to my `ws:outbound-gateway`.

I want to add an identifier to logs in order to relate logs of sending requests and receiving responses in the same message flow. I defined some `UUID` named `messageId` in the integration headers at the beginning of the messaging flow. My question is how can I have the `messageId` or other integration headers of an integration message in such interceptors? Is there any way?

Thanks.

Below is my interceptor class.

```java
package com.asansoft.interceptors;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceClientException;
import org.springframework.ws.client.support.interceptor.ClientInterceptor;
import org.springframework.ws.context.MessageContext;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Mohammad Ghoreishi.
 * moha.gh22@gmail.com
 */

@Component(value = "wsLoggingInterceptor")
public class WSLoggingInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

    private final Logger requestLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("WSRequest");
    private final Logger responseLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("WSResponse");
    private final Logger errorLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("WSError");
    private List<String> exclusionRequestNSList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> exclusionResponseNSList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            messageContext.getRequest().writeTo(byteArrayOutputStream);
            requestLogger.info("Web Service Request : " + removeRequestCredentials(removeSecurityHeaders(new String(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorLogger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            messageContext.getResponse().writeTo(byteArrayOutputStream);
            responseLogger.info("Web Service Response : " + removeResponseCredentials(removeSecurityHeaders(new String(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorLogger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        try {
            long rs = (new Date()).getTime() - responseTime;
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            messageContext.getResponse().writeTo(byteArrayOutputStream);
            errorLogger.error("Web Service Response : " + removeResponseCredentials(removeSecurityHeaders(new String(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
            errorLogger.error("Response Time : " + rs + "ms");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorLogger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Exception ex) throws WebServiceClientException {
        // Blah blah blah
    }


    private String removeSecurityHeaders(String xmlString) {
        // Blah blah blah
    }

    private String removeRequestCredentials(String xmlString) {
        // Blah blah blah
    }

    private String removeResponseCredentials(String xmlString) {
        // Blah blah blah
    }

    public List<String> getExclusionRequestNSList() {
        return exclusionRequestNSList;
    }

    public List<String> getExclusionResponseNSList() {
        return exclusionResponseNSList;
    }

    public void setExclusionRequestNSList(List<String> exclusionRequestNSList) {
        this.exclusionRequestNSList = exclusionRequestNSList;
    }

    public void setExclusionResponseNSList(List<String> exclusionResponseNSList) {
        this.exclusionResponseNSList = exclusionResponseNSList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all take a look, please, into a message history and global wire-tap into a logging channel adapter. This way you would be able to trace all path the message travels through your flow, including headers and payload.

See docs for more info:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management.html#message-history

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/core.html#channel-wiretap

Another way (and only the way) to have the requested info in your WS-specific interceptor is only via a `ThreadLocal` variable. You store that info in some shared `ThreadLocal` before calling `ws:outbound-gateway` and get that info from this variable in your interceptor. Probably you are aware what is MDC in loggers or `SecurityContextHolder` in Spring Security.

You probably could map your custom header into a SOAP request, but that's apparently not what would be good from business perspective to carry that info over the network to the Web Service...

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The `MDC` solved my problem.